# Convert expression to standard geometric progression

Tags: geometric-series

How can I transform a formula describing a curve (a discrete series) to the standard formula for a geometric progression?

(Note: Maths is still very much a foreign language to me. I could be using any of these terms incorrectly. I could be using mathematical notation incorrectly. I could be using MathJax incorrectly. I am trying to describe computer code in mathematical language, and may have any of the translation wrong.)

The existing function computes a sum that is expressed as (I think) the following:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} ({x}+({y}({k-1})^{z}))
$$

- $n$ is an input to the function. It is always an integer > 0.
- $x$, $y$, $z$ are known (static) parameters in the function.

  - In this specific program, $z$ is typically a negative number, such as $-1.1$.
- The function produces the sum of the series, for a given $n$.

Currently I have a function that does this via iterative addition. I want instead to use the [sum of geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = \frac{a(1-r^{n})}{1-r}
$$

What I can't figure out is how to transform this so that:

- The formula meets the geometric series formula, so that $x$, $y$, $z$ are encapsulated instead as appropriate values for $a$ and $r$.
- The $n$ retains the same value i the geometric series formula, so that existing users of this function can feed the same $n$ and get the same result.

If there's some standard transformations that will make this easier, I simply don't know them. I can noodle around in a spreadsheet and watch the plotted results change for n=[1..1000000], but don't understand the mathematical basis of those effects.

How (preferably explaining what the transformation means) do I transform the $x$, $y$, $z$ from the initial expression, to the $a$ and $r$ of the geometric series expression?

Comment: Isn´t it obvious that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} {x}=n\cdot x$?

Comment: Also note that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{\color{red}k} = \frac{a\cdot \color{red}r \cdot  (1-r^{n})}{1-r}$

Comment: @callculus, that's not the same expression though? I think maybe my initial expression is ambiguous; I've added more parentheses to better show what's grouped with what.

Comment: But you still just add $x$ n-times. You can write $\sum_{k=1}^{n} {x}+ y\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} ({k-1})^{z}$ as well.

Comment: @callculus, care to set out an answer? I'm going to need more explanation, I fear :-)

Comment: I´m finished, bignose.

Comment: Is $z$ a positive integer ? Whet is its range ?

Comment: If $z$ is negative, when $k=1$ you have division-by-zero. I assume you have translated your program to math incorrectly (should $k$ start at $2$?). In any case, as Claude implied, this is *not* a Geometric Series since the base is changing in each term of the sum, not the exponent. I did a quick search and I didn't see efficient approximations for the [generalized harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) that appear, so you won't be able to do better than your original code, except for applying a fact like $\sum_{k=2}^nx=(n-1)x$ or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesising from @Claude-Leibovici and @Mark-S:

This is not a Geometric Series since the base is changing in each term of the sum, not the exponent. So, the expression cannot be transformed to the standard geometric progression.

Answer (score 2):

If your formula 
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} ({x}+({y}({k-1})^{z}))$$ is correct, I do not see what you can do except writing (assuming $z >0$)
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x+ y \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1)^z=nx+y\sum_{k=2}^{n} (k-1)^z=nx+y\, H_{n-1}^{(-z)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers.

For sure, for a given integer value of $z$, you can use [Faulhaber's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). If this is the case, you will find the expressions for $z=1,2,\cdots,10$. If you need for larger values of $z$, it is possible to generate them for you in explicit forms easy to code.

Comment: Thanks. In case it's important, $z$ is negative; I have updated the question to clarify this.