# How do I describe the progression $c+ba^{-(n-1)}$? I'm seeking an efficient sum to arbitrary $n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

How do I characterise a progression of the form:
$$
c+ba^{-(n-1)}
$$

where integer $n > 0$.

My motivation is that I'm trying to find an efficient sum for this progression, to an arbitrary $n$. (The existing function sums by iterative addition, which is very inefficient for even moderately large $n$.)

From [asking earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057457/convert-expression-to-standard-geometric-progression) I am informed this is not a geometric progression (and hence I can't use the [sum formula for a geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)).

So, what kind of progression is this, and how do I efficiently sum it, ideally with arithmetic no more complex than exponentiation?

Comment: @dmtri, thanks you were faster than my edit :-) The question now uses $n$ in the expression.

Comment: Note that $$\displaystyle\sum_1^n\Big[c+\frac b{a^{k-1}}\Big]=\sum_1^n c+\sum_1^n\frac b{a^{k-1}}=nc+b\Big[\frac{1-a^{-n}}{1-a^{-1}}\Big]$$ where the second term is the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, would you like to put that into an answer? If not, I can do it.

Comment: Sure, there you go

Answer (score 3):

You have 
$$u_n = c + \frac{b}{a^{n-1}}$$ and you want to find 
$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}u_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left( c + \frac{b}{a^{k-1}}\right) =cn+b\left(1+\frac{1}{a^2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{a^{n-1}}\right) $$
$$ = cn+\frac{b}{a^{n-1}}\left(\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \Big[c+\frac b{a^{k-1}}\Big]
= \sum_{k=1}^n c+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac b{a^{k-1}}
= nc+b\Big[\frac{1-a^{-n}}{1-a^{-1}}\Big]
$$
where the second term is the sum of a geometric progression.